# Unable to access local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Function**:

There's a table of fruits (apple, banana) and their colors (red, yellow).

**Requirement**:

Find a fruit, output its color. If no fruit exists, "no fruit was found".

**Problem**:

The first result is correct ("pear" is not in the table), but subsequent ones are wrong ("pear is red?").

I tried declaring the `color` variable locally using `var color` or `let color` instead of global and that didn't work. I think the scope or test condition I'm using is wrong.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```js
function findFruitColor(table, fruit) {

  let colKey = $(table).find("th:contains('Fruit')").index();
  let colVal = $(table).find("th:contains('Color')").index();

  $(table).find('tr td:nth-child(' + (colKey + 1) + ')').each(function() {

    if ($(this).text() === fruit) {
      color = $(this).siblings('td').addBack().eq(colVal).text();
      return false;
    }

  })


  // if color was found, display it. 
  if (typeof color !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("The color for " + fruit + " is " + color);
  } else {
    console.log("No fruit matching that name was found.");
  }


}


// Call the function
findFruitColor("#myTable", "pear");
findFruitColor("#myTable", "apple");
findFruitColor("#myTable", "pear");
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `color` is global variable so it still be "red" after you run `findFruitColor("#myTable", "apple");`. To solve it, you just need to declare it as local variable of `findFruitColor`. Something like this:

```js
function findFruitColor(table, fruit) {

  let colKey = $(table).find("th:contains('Fruit')").index();
  let colVal = $(table).find("th:contains('Color')").index();
  // Declare color here
  let color;
  
  $(table).find('tr td:nth-child(' + (colKey + 1) + ')').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === fruit) {
      color = $(this).siblings('td').addBack().eq(colVal).text();
      return false;
    }
  })

  // if color was found, display it. 
  if (typeof color !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("The color for " + fruit + " is " + color);
  } else {
    console.log("No fruit matching that name was found.");
  }
}


// Call the function
findFruitColor("#myTable", "pear");
findFruitColor("#myTable", "apple");
findFruitColor("#myTable", "pear");
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cuong Le Ngoc's answer definitely satisfies the base question of "why doesn't this code work?", but have you considered a simpler solution to begin with? At this scale, just loop each row and compare its first column's value to the desired `fruit`, outputting the associated color to the console:

```js
function findFruitColor(table, fruit) {
  let rows = $("#myTable").find("tr");
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let currentRow = $(rows[i]).find("td");
    if (currentRow[0].innerText == fruit) {
      console.log("The color for " + fruit + " is " + currentRow[1].innerText);
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log("No fruit matching the name " + fruit + " was found");
}


// Call the function
findFruitColor("#myTable", "pear");
findFruitColor("#myTable", "apple");
findFruitColor("#myTable", "pear");
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. The actual table has hundreds of rows and multiple columns with unpredictable positions, so it was simplified to a fruit/color fixed 2 column scenario.